# How to find objects which are styled twice (in rule based styling) in QGIS 2.18.10

Tags: qgis, style, rule-based

I have the problem of a complex rule based styling (with 10 different styles and multi-line rules in each style) with several thousands objects. My problem is that the sum of all styled objects in one layer is higher than the actual number of objects in that layer, which means that some objects are included in two different styles and thus are styled twice.

Is there a way to find these objects faster than going through the whole map or through the whole styling rule code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. Didn't know about the sum feature in the style tab and the column duplicate. By clicking on that button the number of duplicates are shown and I can find them much easier!

[image]